# Find The Number Equation Solutions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Find the number of non-negative integer solution of the equation:
$$5x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5}=14$$

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Probably the quickest approach is to note that $x_1$ must be $0,1$, or $2$, and solve three standard $4$-variable [stars-and-bars problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29), one for each possible value of $x_1$. Then add the results to get the final answer.

**Added:** Suppose that $x_1=1$; then $x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=14-5=9$. According to the formula and reasoning in the linked article, this equation has

$$\binom{9+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{12}3$$

solutions in non-negative integers $x_2,x_3,x_4$, and $x_5$. Thus, the original equation has $\binom{12}3$ solutions in which $x_1=1$. Now see how many it has when $x_1=0$ and when $x_1=2$.

Comment: Brian M. Scott please describe me briefly

Comment: @FRM: The formula that you need is in the linked article, which also has a pretty clear explanation of why it works; please try to work from that first.

Comment: @FRM: However, since I’m about to go to bed, I’ve added one of the three cases.